# Can't get the google_play_services_version value after setting the google services API

Tags: android

I've set the Google play services API on my android app project, I did as I saw in the documentation for google android developer. I started by copying the google library services in the folder of my project, then I added the refernce in the build (like we see in the photo the gooogle play services lib is perfectly deployed) and then I tried to copy this piece of code in android but manifiest not recognize the second line. `android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"` [image: (see photo)]

So any help for that please ! Thanks

Comment: looks like you're using the jar and not the project of the lib. So you only have the class and not the resources

Comment: But when I try to add the project Android Studio don't recognize it as I android project should it just past it the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Xavier is right, there are no resources in the [GooglePlayServices JAR file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgoogleplayservicesjar.htm) you usually get your compiled classes.
As you're in Android Studio you can just add to your gradle dependencies : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'`

Comment: Doesn’t works for me, I think that he need the right folder of the project

Comment: Here is a gist of my build.gradle file: `android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
}
` If you still have issues please copy your Manifest and gradle files